# Profile Picture: React Native and Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, react-native, azure-blob-storage

I am developing an app using React-native and Node.js for the server and it has come the time to implement profile picture. I was thinking to use Microsoft Azure Storage, specially Blob Storage service,  to save the file. I know how to use Blob Storage service, so I was thinking to send the image to the server and then from the server to to Azure. However, I think I am using extra steps when I could just send the image from the react-native app.

Anyone know if it is possible to do it in react-native? and how should I implement it?
or maybe there is an easy way for profile picture implementation that you could recommend me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since I haven't used React Native, I am wondering if it has the same restrictions as that of the browser. Can I make cross-domain requests using a React Native application without configuring CORS?

Comment: @GauravMantri I am also a bit new in React-native and in server. What do you mean with configuring CORS?

Comment: @Leticia Can you help me i have same thing? how did you implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Storage JavaScript Client Library to directly upload the photo from the client to Azure Storage: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/tree/master/browser

See the sample here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/browser/samples/sample-blob.html

Comment: the question states "React Native". Your answer points to the web-based Azure Storage JavaScript Client Library

Answer (score 0):

You can upload file/image to azure blob storage using [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob)

**Example Code**

```
const storageURL = 'account_name.blob.core.windows.net';

const assetPath = `${storageURL}/${container_name}/${file_name}.png`;

const file = this.state.selectedImage;

await RNFetchBlob.fetch(
  "PUT",
  `${assetPath}?${sas.token}`,
  {
    "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "x-ms-blob-content-type": file.type
  },
  RNFetchBlob.wrap(file.uri)
)
  .progress((progress) => {
    console.log("Progress ==> ", progress);
  })
  .uploadProgress((progress) => {
    console.log("Upload Progress ==> ", progress);
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Success Response ==> ", JSON.stringify(response));
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("Error at saving image into Azure Storage", JSON.stringify(e));
  })
```